# Commandline email to internal web mail server

Tags: command-line, email

I have a few number of ubuntu pcs, whom I want to mail me some kind of log on daily basis. The problem is that these pcs have access only to the internal webmail (of my campus) and all I can find on google is info regarding sending mails to gmail accounts.
Please help me solve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

If your log uses `syslog` or `rsyslogd`, you could use "remote logging", and skip all the emails. Install the [rsyslog-doc](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=rsyslog-doc) package, and look at `file:///usr/share/doc/rsyslog-doc/html/rsyslog_reliable_forwarding.html`

Answer (score 1):

With the [heirloom-mailx](http://packages.ubuntu.com/heirloom-mailx) [image: Install heirloom-mailx] package installed, you get some SMTP-related options that aren't available with the "plain" `bsd-mailx`. The `mailx` application provided by `heirloom-mailx` can be instructed not to contact a local `sendmail` but a remote SMTP host.

If this works for you, you can put the `set smtp=smtp.xyz.tld` and other commands (e.g. authentication) into a `~/.mailrc` or the `/etc/mail.rc` file to maintain the options at a central point.